# as3 TouchEvent vs MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Just a quick question to those Air expert.

I am develop on Air for iPad app, just wonder is TouchEvent more efficient or MouseEevent is doing fine. i am talking about performance wise, things like doing drag and drop and ect...

Comment: Check these out: [1](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=119),[2](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=122)

Comment: watched them before, best site for new stuff on as3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using touch instead of mouse events, you get a good performance, a smooth drag, and work with multiple fingers.

Comment: can TouchEvent work in conjunction with MouseEvent? meaning can an Air app make use of both types of events?